# AIS parallel interference cancellation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cancellation

I have problem to implementing parallel interference cancellation in matlab with viterbi algorithm. Can anyone introduce me some example code to solve my problem? I have to detect overlapped signals and then demodulate them. note that the modulation scheme is GMSK.

I expect some example matlab codes for parallel interference cancellation.

Comment: could you please show us your code and the problem you are facing? We are here to help, not do the work for you :)